# Arduino IR remote NEC control

Tags: signal, infrared, protocol

I'm trying to build a generic IR remote controlling device using an arduino.

I've done some investigation to discover the IR protocol used by my [NAD SR8](http://www.dynavox.ch/dl/nad_sr8_datasheet.pdf) remote controller.

I've connected a simple IR photodiode to an oscilloscope in order to dump the signal coming from the remote (VOL UP key).

I got the following:

[image]

This signal looks like a NEC IR protocol regarding [the documentation](http://www.mcselec.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=223&Itemid=57). I've decoded the signal:

```
1110 0001 0011 1110 0001 0001 1110 1110
```

I don't know why but this signal does not fully comply with the protocol specification:

[image]

```
[1110] 0001 [0011] 1110 0001 0001 1110 1110
```

Am I wrong somewhere (wrong protocol) ? Is the remote controller broken ?

Comment: Where would the deviation be in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal is indeed NEC, but extended NEC.

There is an extended NEC version which does not invert the address bytes as explained here
http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/nec.php

Comment: This isn't the place to promote your products or funding campaigns.